# Not able to filter the result of LEF JOIN using "AND"

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 2 tables vendor_location and order_location.

Query:

```
SELECT top 10 al.prsnpk,al.serviceid, al.locid al_loc_id, docloc.loc_id doc_loc_id
        from vendor_location al 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT locid FROM dorder_location)
        docloc ON al.locid = docloc.Locid AND al.service_d = 222
```

For this query AND is not working, I mean this query returns data who don't has service id 222.

Comment: add `WHERE` - `LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT locid FROM dorder_location) docloc ON al.locid = docloc.Locid WHERE al.service_d = 222`

Comment: Also, add an `ORDER BY`. A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` means that the data engine is free to return whatever arbitrary rows it wants; this *could* be different **every time** you run the query. Having an `ORDER BY` ensures that consistent results are provided.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk thank you for the response, where is working perfectly.
But why to use where ? why not AND?
When I am doing inner join with AND condition it is working but with left join AND is not working. I want to understand why is it so?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk and I want to add one more inner join on result of above query, with where clause it is not allowing me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query as below and get the corresponding answer.

```
SELECT distinct top 10 al.prsnpk,al.serviceid, al.locid al_loc_id, docloc.loc_id doc_loc_id
FROM vendor_location al LEFT JOIN  dorder_location locid 
     ON al.locid = locid.Locid 
WHERE al.service_d = 222
```

Comment: cant we achive it through AND?

Comment: @Dreamer Having the and as part of the join clause means it only affects what rows you match up to in the dorder_location table. Because it's a left join, this means it has no affect on the rows received from the vendor_location table. `JOIN/ON` is for joining conditions. `WHERE` is for filtering conditions.

Comment: @Dreamer left join causes the entire left list to be returned. Therefore, it will no longer work unless you do a left join directly with another table, or if you first filter the left table and then join with the right table.